# GCE Disk Utilization Metric Inactive even if Stackdriver is enabled

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-container-optimized-os

I have a Compute Engine Instance using a Container-optimized OS. I had setup stackdriver in order to track disk utilization of the VM instance.

I enabled the stackdriver monitoring agent so using the gcloud command

`gcloud compute --project=<PROJECT> instances add-metadata <VM_INSTANCE> --metadata=google-monitoring-enabled=true`

I also enabled set the `google-logging-enabled` metadata to **true** and have restarted the VM each time I updated the metadata as instructed by GCP Documentation.

Upon doing so, I have confirmed that the following containers are running:

- stackdriver-logging-agent
- stackdriver-metadata-agent
- stackdriver-monitoring-agent

Despite this, the GCP Console Metric Explorer indicates that the metric I aim to track (Disk Utilization) is **inactive***. Having said that, my hunch is that there may be a possibility that the logs are not being sent from the VM to GCP.

Any ideas?